# node not recognizing duplicated entries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create a basic MEAN stack CRUD api to add shops into my database. I want every shop to have a unique name (to avoid adding duplicates). So far, everything gets saved into the database even if I post the same request 10 times. Went trough the code a couple of times and can't figure out what's wrong, if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

shop model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

//shop schema
var ShopSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    address: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Shop', ShopSchema);
```

post function:

```
apiRouter.route('/shops')
    //create a shop
    .post(function(req, res) {
        //new instance of shop model
        var shop = new Shop();
        //set the shop information
        shop.name = req.body.name;
        shop.address = req.body.address;
        //save shop and check for errors
        shop.save(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                //duplicate entry
                if(err.code == 11000) {
                    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A shop with that name already exists.'});
                }
                else {
                    return res.send(err);
                }
            }
            else {
                res.json({ message:'Shop created! '});
            }
        });
    })
```

I do not receive errors of any kind, like I said everything just gets written into the database.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your writes haven't finished before the new entries are saved.  You can read more about creating unique keys [Here](https://learnallthenodes.com/episodes/12-unique-records-in-mongoose), but the gist is below.  The solution is to create an index over the unique fields ahead of time.

> When we declare a property to be unique, we’re actually declaring that we want a database-level index on that property. Some database abstraction layers will issue a query to see if a there’s another record with the same value for the unique property, and if that query comes back empty, it allows the save or update to proceed. If you trust this method, you either have incredibly low traffic or you’re about to learn about race conditions, because 2 or more requests could have their checks to the database occur before any writes go out, and you end up with non-unique data in your DB.
>
> In between the time that check query is issued, another insert could come along doing the exact same thing, and you still end up with duplication. Uniqueness can’t be correctly validated at the application level. So it’s good that Mongoose tries to create an index for us.

Comment: found this, using it and works as expected https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator